# Google Apps Script find rows in two arrays that have the same column value

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

```
A = [{ 123, abc}, { 456, abc}, { 111, def}]
B = [{ 123, xyz}, { 111, def}, { 891, def}]
```

I have stored values of a google spreadsheet table in the two arrays A & B.
I now want to create a new array C that only has the rows of array A where the first column of A matches the first column of B.

Note: The first column is a unique ID. There won't be any duplicates within each array's first column.

In the example given this would result in:

```
c =  [{ 123, abc}, { 111, def}]
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

This code does what you want.  I've tested it.  You can view the LOGS, and see the results.
The code creates two new objects from the arrays of objects.

```
var A = [{ 123:"abc"}, { 456:"abc"}, { 111:"def"}];
```

Is used to create:

```
var newObjA = {123:"abc", 456:"abc", 111:"def"};
```

And the same for array B.  Then the code loops through the newObjA, and uses the key from each element in newObjA to look for a key of the same value in newObjB.  If there is a match, a value is returned.  If there is no matching key of the same value, then `undefined` is returned.

If `undefined` is returned, then there is no match, and no data get put into the final array.  If there is a match, the matching element from newObjA is put into the final array.

There is a lot of data manipulation to retrieve and move data from one format into another.  You'll need to study the code to figure it out.

```
function compareData() {
  var A = [{ 123:"abc"}, { 456:"abc"}, { 111:"def"}];
  var B = [{ 123:"xyz"}, { 111:"def"}, { 891:"def"}];

  Logger.log("A: " + A);
  Logger.log("B: " + B);

  var arryLengthA = A.length;
  var arryLengthB = B.length;

  var newObjA = {};
  var newObjB = {};
  var finalArry  = [];
  var thisIterationObj = {};

  //Convert Array A to an Ojbect A
  for (var i = 0; i < arryLengthA; i++) {
    Logger.log("count: " + i);
    thisIterationObj = {}; //reset to empty
    thisIterationObj = A[i];
    Logger.log("thisIterationObj: " + thisIterationObj);

    for (var thisKey in thisIterationObj) {
      Logger.log("thisKey: " + thisKey);
      Logger.log(thisIterationObj[thisKey]);

      newObjA[thisKey] = thisIterationObj[thisKey];
      Logger.log(newObjA[thisKey]);
    }
  };

  //Convert Array B to an Ojbect B
  for (var i = 0; i < arryLengthB; i++) {
    Logger.log("count: " + i);
    thisIterationObj = {}; //reset to empty
    thisIterationObj = B[i];
    Logger.log("thisIterationObj: " + thisIterationObj);

    //Create a new object of all values in array B
    for (var thisKey2 in thisIterationObj) {
      Logger.log("thisKey2: " + thisKey2);
      Logger.log(thisIterationObj[thisKey2]);

      newObjB[thisKey2] = thisIterationObj[thisKey2];
      Logger.log(newObjB[thisKey2]);
    }
  };

  //Compare Object A to Object B
  for (var keyObjA in newObjA) {
    thisIterationObj = {};
    //Find key of objA in objB

    var theMatch = newObjB[keyObjA];
    Logger.log("newObjB[keyObjA]: " + newObjB[keyObjA]);

    if (theMatch != undefined) {
      Logger.log("newObjB[keyObjA] " + newObjB[keyObjA]);
      thisIterationObj[keyObjA] = newObjA[keyObjA];
      finalArry.push(thisIterationObj);
    };
  };

  //Test the final result by looping through and displaying all values in the final array
  Logger.log("finalArry: " + finalArry);
  Logger.log("finalArry length: " + finalArry.length);

  //This code is a check to test for the correct result
  for (var i = 0; i < finalArry.length; i++) {
    thisIterationObj = {}; //reset to blank
    thisIterationObj = finalArry[i];

    for (var finalKey in thisIterationObj)
    Logger.log("finalArry value: " + i + ": " + finalKey + " : " + thisIterationObj[finalKey]);

  };
};
```